# RSpec documentation...where is it hiding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

Having a terrible time finding **RSpec-2** (and **rspec-rails**) documentation. Specifically I want to look up all available Matchers... but how?

I've tried:

- [RSpec.info](http://rspec.info/) : outdated - RSpec 1.x
- [rdoc.info](http://rdoc.info/gems/rspec/2.2.0/frames) : seems useless, to me anyway. (incomplete?)
- [RSpec-Relish](http://relishapp.com/rspec) : confusing. incomplete? how would one look up available Matchers?
- [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/rspec/rspec/wiki) : scattered info. unorganized. incomplete?

Yes, I'm aware of [The Book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book)...but, seriously, isn't this stuff online?

Even tried `rake doc:plugins` but it didn't work. Too green to know why...

apparently there used to be some decent 1.x docs on [rspec.rubyforge.org](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html). but they're appear to be long gone...

Where are these docs hiding?

Comment: +1 for cool question title

Comment: As of Dec 27 2013, 2.14.3 is the latest. http://rdoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/2.14.3/frames. You can find Built-in matchers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure why you feel rdoc.info isn't useful - here's the matcher docs there:

http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/2.0.1/RSpec/Matchers

It may be that you're looking in the wrong spot; these were in the RSpec::Expectations gem, which is split out from the core in Rspec 2.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful! I must be using rdoc.info site wrong as I search for "rspec" and get: `http://rdoc.info/gems/rspec/2.2.0/frames`. then try to search for matcher and get nothing. and if I browse I get lost/confused in multiple embedded frames.

Comment: OK, please bear with me... I'm trying to learn Ruby/Rails and finding it incredibly difficult to look things up that I find in code... for example: using the **rubydoc.info** site I've tried searching for `mock_model` and came up empty...again. Same thing with `as_null_object`.  This is the most confusing documentation I've ever come across... Sure I *could* Google, and I have been, but that's a shotgun approach. How should I be approaching the "problem" of looking up and understanding some method/symbol, etc. that I come across in Ruby/Rails/RSpec/JQuery code?

Comment: What I do is create a package at Railsapi.com, download it, and unzip it to my local hard drive.  Then I create a fluid single-site-browser (I'm on mac, use prism on linux or windows) pointed at the index file from the package.  railsapi.com's docs have a pretty good search index built into them, so I usually start there.  If i can't find what I need in that, then I'll hit up rdoc.info with some educated guesses about where the docs ought to be.  Google is my last resort.

Comment: for example, typing "mock_model" into my railsapi.com docs browser points to one result, Spec::Rails::Mocks.  "as_null_object" gives me two results, one in Spec::Mocks::Methods and one in Spec::Mocks::Proxy.  Neither has much in the way of documentation, but both can show the source of the method in question, and both have links to github as well.

Comment: Excellent! On a Mac as well... I'll look into railsapi.com. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 18):

The first place to go is the official [Relish docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/), they have gotten a significant improvement over the years and are now my first place to look.

At the time of writing this answer originally, this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2353100) was solid. It contains matchers for the following:

- [Capybara](https://gist.github.com/2353100#file-capybara-md)
- [Paperclip with Shoulda](https://gist.github.com/2353100#file-paperclip-matchers-md)
- [Rspec Rails](https://gist.github.com/2353100#file-rails-matchers-md)
- [Rspec Exceptions](https://gist.github.com/2353100#file-rspec-expectations-md)
- [Shoulda Matchers](https://gist.github.com/2353100#file-shoulda-matchers-md)

Comment: This, to me, is a great answer.